# Facebook Like Button Error?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

1. After first page access, OK through the OK button, then Cancel, OK, Press the OK button again to display the error message.
   Clicking on the statement will reveal a pop-up at the URL below.
   https://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/coded?code=1404078&message=Action+Blocked%3A+You+have+been+temporarily+blocked+from+performing+this+action.&hash=AQCiVCUcn3lEZAEx

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm5i3.png)

There was no problem until 6 p.m. but I checked the symptoms from 10 a.m. on January 18th.

2. After first page contact, the "FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create' ~" function is not working.
   Okay, then cancel it and press OK again to start working.

Comment: What is unclear? The message tells you exactly what’s up - your account just has been temporarily blocked from liking pages. If you perform extensive “tests” on the like button (like canceling, or revoking likes and then giving them again), this can easily happen.

Comment: I agree with @CBroe that the error message is self explanatory. Which is not clear is your question, but I've added an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Why I am blocked I can't use like button?**
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=938387366225423&rdrhc

> **Facebook Help Community**
> This maybe because you're blocked temporary due using this feature too fast, visit this link to know more information about the block: https://www.facebook.com/support/